# Collection View

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using collection view ,in that there is collection images if i tap any one image it will move to next screen where the user can able to enter the details of the picture in textview and if user press save button in 2nd view controller it should save the text and move to first view controller and should put one mark symbol for showing this image has notes .like such

For that what i did is ,
I created one dictionary that stores the touched image as key and value as entered string in the second view controller .i don't after this , i want to mark a symbol if user goes to previous screen .
Please help me to do this

```
  //collection view methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView
{
return 1;

 }
 -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return [self.imageArray count];

}

   -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

PicturesCollectionViewCell *Cell1 = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"%@",self.imageArray);

Cell1.self.imageView.image=[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Cell1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
Cell1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

//button to tap

UIButton *tapButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];

tapButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 96, 82);

[tapButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Tap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[tapButton setTag:indexPath.row];

[Cell1.contentView addSubview:tapButton];

self.imageSelected = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@" the image is:%@",self.imageSelected);

return Cell1;
 }
     -(IBAction)Tap:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

self.key = @(btn.tag);
int tag = [self.key intValue];
self.imageSelected = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:tag];
NSLog(@" image selected in picture confirm screen %@",self.imageSelected);
NotesViewController *NotesVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotesVC"];
NotesVC.self.notes_Array = self.imageSelected;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:NotesVC animated:YES];

    }

    2nd view controller -Notes View Controller
  - (IBAction)bnt_Save_Notes:(id)sender {

   if (self.txtview_Notes.text.length == 0) {

    [StaticHelper showAlertWithTitle:nil message:@"Notes Should  Not be empty" onViewController:self];

}

else
{


    self.string = self.txtview_Notes.text;

    NSLog(@" the noted string is :%@",self.string);





    PicViewController *PictureVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PictureVC"];
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    [dict setObject:self.string forKey:self.notes_Array];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];



}
```

Please say some ideas to do this .

Comment: you just need to modify your datasource at that indexpath, so that when you reload the table, you can see the checkmark in the cell,

Comment: Thanks @Teja Nandamuri,but i didn't send the dictionary to first view controller .and where i have to reloads the collection view cell. and if user touch the same picture which they gave details the entered text should be there in second view controller .Please say this

Comment: your code's strange formatting doesnt encourage to read it.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a dictionary in your collection view controller, and this dic should hold info whther the cell should have checked or not. you can use the keys as indexpath,

For example:

In your collection view controller:

```
 dictionary = @{ @"1" : @[ your-data, NO],
                 @"2" : @[ your-data, NO],
                 @"3" : @[ your-data, NO]};

   here keys @"1",@"2",@"3" serve as indexpath
```

and when you click the image, in the didSelectRow delegate method, pass this dictionary along with the indexPath to the secondView controller and modify it in the second view controller.

And once you come back from second view controller, pass this dictionary to your collection view controller

```
     dictionary = @{ @"1" : @[ your-data, NO],
                 @"2" : @[ your-data, YES],
                 @"3" : @[ your-data, NO]};
```

and reload your collection view.

Comment: @thanks Teja Nandamuri, shall i send a code ,please look at my code ?

Comment: you can try the way I suggested, and if you still can't, update your question with what you tried, and we can help from there.

Comment: actually i tried to send a dictionary from second view controller to first view controller using delegate.but i run through a breakpoint the control is not going properly.

Comment: ,I got the dictionary in First View Controller ,now ,if i touch again the same image i want show the entered text in notes view controller …for that what i want to do.Please help me